# Why the following temp and stNode are showing different values?

Tags: c

Please look at the following code. I'm trying to create a linked list by calling insertNode() but why stNode is not returning the allocated temp node whereas temp is returning the same?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
int data;
struct node* link;
};

struct node *insertNode(struct node*stNode,int data)
{
    struct node* temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->link = NULL;

    if(stNode)
    {
        stNode=temp;
    }
    printf("stNode->data in insertNode is %d\n",stNode->data);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    struct node * list1;
    struct node * temp;
    temp = insertNode(list1,5);
    printf("In main\n");
    printf("temp->data  = %d\t, temp->link  = %u\n",temp->data,temp->link);
    printf("list1->data = %d\t, list1->link = %u\n",list1->data,list1->link);
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
stNode->data in insertNode is 5
In main
temp->data  = 5 , temp->link  = 0
list1->data = 11865500  , list1->link = 10636298
```

The above output shows different for temp and list1. Why is it so?

Comment: Undefined behavior, using the value of an object with automatic storage duration that was uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

`stNode` is just a local variable and will vanish on exiting `insertNode`.

To modiry `list1` in `main` function, use pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};

struct node *insertNode(struct node**stNode,int data)
{

    struct node* temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->link = NULL;

    if(stNode)
    {
        *stNode=temp;
    }
    printf("stNode->data in insertNode is %d\n",(*stNode)->data);
    return temp;

}

int main(void)
{
    struct node * list1;
    struct node * temp;
    temp = insertNode(&list1,5);
    printf("In main\n");
    printf("temp->data  = %d\t, temp->link  = %p\n",temp->data,(void*)temp->link);
    printf("list1->data = %d\t, list1->link = %p\n",list1->data,(void*)list1->link);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually modify the parameter value. The correct way would be:

```
    struct node *insertNode(struct node** stNode,int data)
    {
    ...
       if(stNode)
       {
           *stNode=temp;
       }
    ...
    }

    main()
    {
        ...
        temp = insertNode(&list1,5);

    }
```